Godot System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCastAny(System.Void*, object): System.InvalidCastException
So I have an array and a local variable to hold a single item from that array for use. For some reason that is completely beyond me Godot seems to be casting the type returned from the array (completely unnecessary) and then is somehow failing at this cast.
PathNode current_door = null, match_door = null;
Array<PathNode> free_doors = new Array<PathNode>();

. . .

match_door = free_doors[rand.RandiRange(0, free_doors.Count - 1)];

As one can see, it does not need to cast at all, the variable is the type that is being returned from the array. So could someone explain to me why Godot insists on doing this unneeded and for some reason breaking task.
Here is the full error:
E 0:00:03:0669   object System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCastAny(System.Void*, object): System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Godot.Node3D' to type 'FireBrand.Entities.Navigation.PathNode'.
  <C++ Error>    System.InvalidCastException
  <C++ Source>   :0 @ object System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCastAny(System.Void*, object)
  <Stack Trace>  :0 @ object System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCastAny(System.Void*, object)
                 VariantUtils.generic.cs:385 @ T Godot.NativeInterop.VariantUtils.ConvertTo<T>(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant&)
                 Array.cs:1409 @ T Godot.Collections.Array`1.get_Item(int)
                 DungeonMaster.cs:167 @ void FireBrand.General.DungeonMaster+<BuildDungeon>d__31.MoveNext()
                 :0 @ void System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                 :0 @ void System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(object)
                 GodotSynchronizationContext.cs:51 @ void Godot.GodotSynchronizationContext.ExecutePendingContinuations()
                 GodotTaskScheduler.cs:76 @ void Godot.GodotTaskScheduler.Activate()
                 ScriptManagerBridge.cs:82 @ void Godot.Bridge.ScriptManagerBridge.FrameCallback()


What language are you using?

@Camwin C#. I circumvented the problem ultimately by rewriting the code, but I would still be curious to know why this is possible in Godot.
